# Where did that strange flower vanish in Tuvix?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the Star Trek: Voyager S02E24, we come across a strange breed of flower which melds with a life form to breed. This same flower creates Tuvix, a half Tuvok, half Neelix creature.  However, at the end, when Kath forces Tuvix to go through the Transporter and Separate, we see Tuvok and Neelix, but no flower; whereas, in the experiments which were carried out prior, in those which worked we see the strange flower + the other flower. Is this a directing mistake, or did the flower get halved and meld with both the guys even after their separation?

Comment: I'm sure Janeway killed it off camera, like she murdered Tuvix.

Answer (score -1):

They used a radioisotope that "attaches itself to the DNA of one of the merged species, but not the other."  There is not another indicator.

This would suggest that the one who did not have the radioisotope attached to his DNA, might still be merged with the flower, as nothing was done to separate it.

I think that, in the test case, there were two flowers merged, not three, and thus two flowers when separated.

All of this is extrapolation from the words spoken in the episode, however.